# how to get NAT's external port when create connection to external host and how to implement STUN in Java

Tags: java, protocols, traversal, nat, stun

I'm studying about NAT and STUN protocol, but I haven't comprehended them, so I tried to implement STUN in Java.

Let's say I have 2 computers which are connected to Internet by 2 respective full-cone NAT devices, and I'm trying to implement STUN protocol in Java and I just implement the part when 2 peers both know external IP and Port of each other, and one of them (let's call this peer is "client") is trying to send a message to other one (and this peer is "server"). And I did something like this:

- **On the server**, I opened a socket by:

  ```
  ServerSocket sv = new ServerSocket(0);
  ```

  Then I get ip of server by this site http://www.whatismyip.com, and get the port which is opened by:

  ```
  System.out.println(sv.getLocalPort());
  ```
- **On the client**, I send a message to server by:

  ```
  Socket sk = new Socket(serverIP, serverPort);
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sk.getOutputStream(), true);
  pw.print("Hello there");
  pw.close();
  sk.close();
  ```

But the server could not receive anything, so I have some questions:

1. I think server's external port I got by above way is not the external port which will be used by another peer to send message to server, so what is the right way to get it in Java?
2. The way I did is the right way to implement the part of STUN when 2 peer know each other's external ip and port after exchange with STUN server? if it's not, what is the right way?

Hope you all explain for me, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Most NAT systems will not open a tunnel for a listening socket that is in the private address space. You must either ask the administrator to open a port for you and communicate the port to the remote peer, or you must use something like [uPNP's Internet Gateway Device Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol) (not actually standardized, but many routers implement it) to request that the NAT open a specific port for you.

From what I can read of the [STUN RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389), it *appears* to make the assumption that the port used to communicate with the STUN coordination server will be the same port a client may use to connect to the first STUN peer. This seems like a surprising assumption for an RFC to make as it places an incredible burden on a NAT router to hand out the same port to the same client repeatedly, drastically complicating the NAT packet delivery rules. I hope I'm wrong here.

Comment: my NAT devices are just modems, so of course i can open any ports, but i'm trying to implement a part of STUN protocol to traverse through NAT, can you suggest me a simple method to implement it in JAVA. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [Wikipedia External Links for STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN#External_links) -- two different Java STUN implementations are linked. I hope one can provide you with the inspiration you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a well-known STUN server that sits somewhere in public internet to act as a coordinator. Such STUN server helps two peers to discover each other's public address and port. The fact that you have full-cone NAT only helps after peers know each other and begin to communicate. If it isn't full-cone, STUN server may need to relay all traffics between peers!

The most related specifications are:

- [ICE](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5245.txt)
- [STUN](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5389.txt)
- [TURN](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5766.txt)

As for Java implementation, I find [littleshoot stun stack](https://github.com/adamfisk) is in quite good shape.